# Should I use composite primary keys if I use JPA and the keys can change?

Tags: database, jpa, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I'm a little confused if I should use composite primary keys or surrogate keys.

Initially I wanted to use composite primary keys when they were needed so have a more clear database, but some parts of the keys could change and JPA doesn't allow to update an object's primary key.

For example I have a Product entity that has a primary key composed of a String code and another entity Account. The code can be updated, but with JPA I can only do that with JPQL which I'd like to avoid. Is it good in this case to use an auto incremented primary key?

Does this mean that the only solution is to use surrogate keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, according specification JPA does not support update of primary keys:

> The application must not change the value of the primary key[10]. The
>   behavior is undefined if this occurs.[11]
>   ...
>   [10] This includes not
>   changing the value of a mutable type that is primary key or an
>   attribute of a composite primary key.
>   [11] The implementation may, but
>   is not required to, throw an exception. Portable applications must not
>   rely on any such specific behavior.

Using surrogate key is in my opinion best option, most of the time also auto incremented one.

Other option would be removal of entity with original key and recreating it with new key (and other values from original entity). That is plenty of work, especially for entities with many relationships.